# Multiple forms in react

Tags: reactjs

I have multiple forms like below

```
<form>
  <TextField ..../>
  <TextField ..../>  
   Calling another child component here
</form>
```

Child Component also has a form like below

```
<form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onTrigger)}>
  <TextField ..../>
  <select ..../> 
   <Button variant="contained" type="submit">Submit</Button> 
</form>
```

How can I handle these two forms in one submit operation. Is it possible? I'm new to react, please share your insights.

Answer (score 0):

You could make both forms controlled components, i.e. store the input values
in state variables whenever they change. Then, you use the same onSubmit function for both forms.

Maybe it'd be easier if you used only one form if that's possible.

Comment: One form is not possible

Comment: Well, still, the first sketch I gave works with two forms also.

Comment: Will check it and let you know.

Comment: Could you please elaborate more on your solution?

Answer (score -1):

I really recommend Formik, you can read more about it here:
https://formik.org/docs/overview

Here is an example of exactly what you want (look how short it is):

CodeSandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/wu7yj

You should have three files:

App.jsx

```
import React from "react";
import FormA from "./FormA";
import FormB from "./FormB";

export default function App() {
  const [formData, setFormData] = React.useState({
    formA: { values: null, validated: false },
    formB: { values: null, validated: false },
  });

  const formAref = React.useRef();
  const formBref = React.useRef();

  React.useEffect(() => {
    if (formData.formB.validated && formData.formA.validated) {
      alert("Ready to save");
    }
  }, [formData]);

  async function handleSubmit() {
    await formAref.current.Submit();
    await formBref.current.Submit();
  }

  function handleChangeFormA(data) {
    setFormData({ ...formData, formA: data });
  }

  function handleChangeFormB(data) {
    setFormData({ ...formData, formB: data });
  }

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>

      <FormA onChange={handleChangeFormA} refId={formAref} />
      <FormB onChange={handleChangeFormB} refId={formBref} />

      <button
        onClick={() => {
          console.log(formData);
        }}
        type="button"
      >
        set
      </button>

      <button onClick={handleSubmit} type="button">
        Submit
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

FormA.jsx

```
import React from "react";
import { useFormik } from "formik";
import * as Yup from "yup";

const FormA = ({ onChange, refId }) => {
  const formik = useFormik({
    initialValues: {
      name: "",
      email: ""
    },
    validationSchema: Yup.object({
      name: Yup.string().required("This field is required"),
      email: Yup.string()
        .email("Invalid email address")
        .required("Email is required")
    }),
    onSubmit: () => {
      watchForm();
    }
  });

  // React.useEffect(() => {
  //   watchForm();
  // }, [formik.values, formik.errors]);

  React.useImperativeHandle(refId, () => ({
    Submit: async () => {
      await formik.submitForm();
    }
  }));

  function watchForm() {
    if (onChange) {
      onChange({
        values: formik.values,
        validated: formik.isSubmitting
          ? Object.keys(formik.errors).length === 0
          : false
      });
    }
  }

  return (
    <form ref={refId}>
      <div className={"form"}>
        <h3>Form A</h3>
        <div>
          <label>Name </label>
          <input
            name="name"
            value={formik.values.name}
            onBlur={formik.handleBlur}
            onChange={formik.handleChange}
          />
          {formik.errors.name && (
            <div style={{ color: "red" }}>
              <small>{formik.errors.name}</small>
            </div>
          )}
        </div>
        <br />
        <div>
          <label>Email </label>
          <input
            name="email"
            value={formik.values.email}
            onBlur={formik.handleBlur}
            onChange={formik.handleChange}
          />
          {formik.errors.email && (
            <div style={{ color: "red" }}>
              <small>{formik.errors.email}</small>
            </div>
          )}
        </div>
        <pre>{JSON.stringify(formik.values, null, 2)}</pre>
      </div>
    </form>
  );
};

export default FormA;
```

Formb.jsx

```
import React from "react";
import { useFormik } from "formik";
import * as Yup from "yup";

const FormB = ({ onChange, refId }) => {
  const formik = useFormik({
    initialValues: {
      phone: ""
    },
    validationSchema: Yup.object({
      phone: Yup.string()
        .required("This field is required")
        .min(6, "At least 06 characters")
    }),
    onSubmit: () => {
      watchForm();
    }
  });

  // React.useEffect(() => {
  //   watchForm();
  // }, [formik.values, formik.errors]);

  React.useImperativeHandle(refId, () => ({
    Submit: async () => {
      await formik.submitForm();
    }
  }));

  function watchForm() {
    if (onChange) {
      onChange({
        values: formik.values,
        validated: formik.isSubmitting
          ? Object.keys(formik.errors).length === 0
          : false
      });
    }
  }

  return (
    <form ref={refId}>
      <div className={"form"}>
        <h3>Form B</h3>
        <div>
          <label>Phone number </label>
          <input
            name="phone"
            value={formik.values.phone}
            onBlur={formik.handleBlur}
            onChange={formik.handleChange}
          />
          {formik.errors.phone && (
            <div style={{ color: "red" }}>
              <small>{formik.errors.phone}</small>
            </div>
          )}
        </div>

        <pre>{JSON.stringify(formik.values, null, 2)}</pre>
      </div>
    </form>
  );
};

export default FormB;
```

Comment: Let me check the example.

Comment: @Ganesh I added the code here to make it easier.

Comment: Sure, I will check it later on the day. Will update here.